# Display inline-block pushing final element below other elements

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id='Content'>
<div>
    <div>
        <pre>SOME TEXT</pre>
        <div id='map1' style='width:450px;height:350px;'></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre>SOME TEXT</pre>
        <div id='map2' style='width:450px;height:350px;margin-left:-17px;'></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style='width:300px;'>
    <h1>Contact Us</h1><br>
    <form action="/Account/Contact" onsubmit="return SubmitMessageForm(this,event,this.childNodes[1]);" method="post">
        <pre style="display:none;"></pre>
        <label>
            <span>Person To Email</span>
            <select name='ToContact' id='ToContact'>
                <option value='0'>Mark</option>
                <option value='1'>Paul</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Name</span>
            <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name"/>
        </label><br>
        <label>
            <span>Your Email</span>
            <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email"/>
        </label><br>
        <label>
            <span>Message</span>
            <textarea name="Message" rows="8" id="Message"></textarea>
        </label><br>
        <label><input style='width:50px;' type="submit" value="Send"/></label>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body > div#Content {
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
body >div#Content >div {
    display:inline-block;
}
    body >div#Content >div >div {

    }
        body >div#Content >div >div >pre {
            line-height:20px;
            margin-right:50px;
        }
        body >div#Content >div >div >div {
            display:inline-block;
        }
        body >div#Content >div >div >h1 {
            font-size:20px;
        }
        body >div#Content >div >form {
            width:100%;
        }
            body >div#Content >div >form >label {
                float:left;
            }
                body >div#Content >div >form >label >span {
                    float:left;
                }
                body >div#Content >div >form >label >input, body >div#Content >div >form >label >textarea, body >div#Content >div >form >label >select {
                    width:300px;
                    float:left;
                }
```

I'm trying to display two div elements side by side, but the second div is pushed down by about 500px for some reason. How do I make these two elements go side by side but also be aligned in the center of the parent div? When I try to remove display:inline-block and add float left it doesn't center

[image: What it currently looks like]

Comment: This question would be better with a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: could you add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Code is posted, copy and paste anyone? lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `vertical-align:top;` on the inline element. This should render it side by side

Also heads up, the code you posted doesnt validate.. http://jsfiddle.net/wJtmq/

Comment: That fixed it thankyou, I don't know why it doesn't validate it works perfectly fine, jsfiddle doesn't even seem to recognize the closing form tag.

Comment: Please accept ;) I dont really have time to look at it all just make sure that you close tags in the right order. You can use the w3 validater to clear anything up

Comment: I can't accept for another 5 minutes, but I will when I can. :)

Comment: Oh okay, sorry I forgot about that. Cheers